# If you make a gif using Python Pillow, the color will disappear

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was going to make a total of 360 copies of my light bulb atmospheric pressure picture at 1-degree intervals and make it a gif.
However, if you make it with gif and look at the results, the color is gone.
There are definitely colors in the original picture

I think Pillow is weird, so I tried with imageio, but the same problem occurs

I don't know how to solve this problem

```
# image code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import imageio
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

file_list = os.listdir("./")
file_png = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith(".png")]
 
path = [f"./{i}" for i in file_png]
 
paths = [Image.open(i) for i in path]
 
imageio.mimsave('./simul2.gif', paths, fps = 60)

# pillow code
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
 
al = []

for i in np.arange(0, 360, 1):
  st = "{}.png".format(i)
  al.append(st)

frames = []
for j in al:
  new_frame = Image.open(j)
  frames.append(new_frame)
 
frames[0].save('simul1.gif', format = 'GIF',
               append_images = frames[1:],
               save_all = True,
               duration = 1,
               loop = 0)
```

~

this is my original image and one cut of result gif

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: put code without line numbers - it will be simpler to copy and run it.

Comment: Python doesn't need `./` in path to open it. You don't need `[f"./{i}" for i in file_png]`. And you can use `listdir()` instead of `listdir('./')`

Comment: `png` can use `24-bits` and `32-bits` colors but `gif` only `8-bits` colors - so it could reduce colors. Or it could remove `transparency` (`alpha channel`) because `gif` can't use `alpha channel`

Comment: If you look closely, there’s a bit of color – maybe the first ones that appeared up to the GIF palette size. Could you post enough source images to reproduce the issue with, for our testing convenience?

Comment: I modified the original picture to 10 pages

Comment: Just to verify, you're trying to create an animated GIF out of 360 individual PNGs?  Is that the gist of it?  Perhaps you should save them all as individual GIFs first, so they all get converted to palettized.

Comment: I'm studying meteorology.
The reason why this picture is necessary is that it is difficult to analyze by looking at one area of the bulb pressure field, so it is necessary to check the bulb.
In addition to atmospheric pressure, we're going to draw data such as temperature and horizontal wind.
So I just changed the hardness, so this picture needs to be rotated

Comment: @이수현 completely unrelated but based on your last comment, why not use 3D over GIF?

Comment: Try other animated image formats, APNG or WebP, they handle colour much better that GIF does

Comment: @Nikolaj Š. I switched to the appng and worked on it, so it worked out! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible without more details. The earlier comments about different color palettes seem like good guesses, but without information about how your input images were generated (what number of colors etc) I don't think this is a useful question.

Comment: The GIF format only can handle 256 colors, maximum.  If you have more than that in your source, you're going to lose some, and the ones you lose might not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are not prepared in an ideal way for PIL to work with. First, they have a superfluous alpha channel which prevents PIL from using a decent quantisation algorithm and secondly, they are RGB rather than palette, despite having so few colours. As such, you are going to need to *"hold PIL's hand a little"* and guide it to where you want to go.

So, initially I would suggest this approach, which can be modified if other factors show up:

- load first image - ***as long as colours are representative of entire sequence***, if not load several and join into a larger image to get all the colours,
- ditch the alpha channel,
- convert to palette mode, using *"median cut"* quantisation
- extract the palette and put to one side to be used in all frames in the output GIF
- load your other images, ditching the alpha channel as you go
- save all your images, as you already are doing, but force a common palette

It's easier than it sounds, here are the steps:

```
from PIL import Image

frames = []
# Load first image, ditch alpha channel, quantise and extract palette
im = Image.open('first.png').convert('RGB').quantize(method=Image.Quantize.MEDIANCUT, dither=False)
frames.append(im)

# Extract palette and put aside
palette = im.getpalette()

# Load other images, ditch alpha and append to list
for i in otherImages:
    im = Image.open(i).convert('RGB')
    frames.append(im)

# Save all frames with common palette
frames[0].save('simul1.gif', format = 'GIF',
           append_images = frames[1:],
           save_all = True,
           duration = 1,
           loop = 0,
           palette=palette)
```

Comment: You’ve gone very quiet. How did you get on with my suggestion?